# Comparing lists with their indices and content in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, networkx

I have a list of numbers as

```
N = [13, 14, 15, 25, 27, 31, 35, 36, 43]
```

After some calculations, for each element in `N`, I get the following list as the answers.

```
ndlist = [4, 30, 0, 42, 48, 4, 3, 42, 3]
```

That is, for the first index in `N` (which is 13), my answer is 4 in `ndlist`.

For some indices in `N`, I get the same answer in `ndlist`. For example, when `N= 13` and `31`, the answer is `4` in ndlist.

I need to find the numbers in `N` (13 and 31 in my  example) such that they have the same answer in `ndlist`.

Can someone help me to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and put those into a list keyed by the answer like:

#### Code:

```
N = [13, 14, 15, 25, 27, 31, 35, 36, 43]
ndlist = [4, 30, 0, 42, 48, 4, 3, 42, 3]

from collections import defaultdict
answers = defaultdict(list)
for n, answer in zip(N, ndlist):
    answers[answer].append(n)

print(answers)
print([v for v in answers.values() if len(v) > 1])
```

#### Results:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {4: [13, 31], 30: [14], 
            0: [15], 42: [25, 36], 48: [27], 3: [35, 43]})

[[13, 31], [25, 36], [35, 43]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried and got the same answer. But I need only the values inside square brackets. For example, [13,31], [25,36], [35,43]. Can we get it like that?

Comment: `[v for v in answers.values() if len(v) > 1]`  But then how will you which is goes with?

Comment: Thanks Stephen! I actually don't need the class. I need only the list which has 2 or more numbers.

Comment: @ Stephen, now I'd like to connect the number  'v for v in answers.values() if len(v) == 1' with its corresponding ndlist value. How can I do that? For example, 14 and 30 in the previous list.

Comment: `{k: v for k, v in answers.items() if len(v) == 1}`

Comment: You have a nested loop.  No way to tell what is going on in a comment.  I suggest you spend a little time and formulate a new question.

Comment: @ Stephen, done!  here's the link; 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621514/accessing-elements-in-a-list-python

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using only a nested list comprehension:

```
[N[idx] for idx, nd in enumerate(ndlist) if nd in [i for i in ndlist if ndlist.count(i)>1]]

#[13, 25, 31, 35, 36, 43]
```

To explain: the inner list comprehension (`[i for i in ndlist if ndlist.count(i)>1]`) gets all duplicate values in `ndlist`, and the rest of the list comprehension extracts the corresponding values in `N` where those values are found in `ndlist`