# Accessing elements in a list Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, networkx

I have a list of answers as follows:

```
answers = defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {38: [0, 17], 19: [2], 5: [14], 3: [21], 1: [23, 32], 25: [26], 42: [28, 40], 34: [31], 12: [43, 46]})
```

Now I'm trying to connect the points as follows:

```
for v in answers.values():
    if len(v)>1:
        T.add_edge(v[0],v[1])
```

This works fine, but when the length of answers.values() is 1, like in `(...., 19: [2], ...)` I need to connect 2 with its corresponding class value (which is 19). How can I access the class value in the above `answers` list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to keep track of the keys and the value in that dict like:

```
for k, v in answers.items():
    if len(v) > 1:
        T.add_edge(v[0], v[1])
    else:
        T.add_edge(k, v[0])
```